# Activation Lock on iPhone 4S randomly appeared (not my username, I am the only owner)

Tags: iphone, apple-id, activation-lock

While listening to Spotify on my old iPhone 4S, the screen changed and showed the Activation Lock screen.  Spotify continued to play while the activation lock was on.  This phone is not set up or connected to any carrier, and I only use it for music and games, so it is only connected to my home WiFi (which is password protected).

The strange thing is that I purchased this phone from AT&T back in 2013, and I have been the only owner of the phone, but it is saying my Apple ID is not the original Apple ID, and will not let me Activate the phone.  What is interesting is that it does seem to be someone with a similar name to mine.

I like having the spare iPhone for listening to music and playing games separate from my current phone.  How do I get my phone back?

Answer (score 4):

Take it to an apple store, they will check if it is really yours, and if it is they will remove it. Also, check your find my iphone settings after it is fixed.